# ERROR: open:/etc/bind/named.conf: permission denied on restarting bind9 service

Tags: permissions, debian, webm, bind9

I have Debian and Bind9 and Webmin

Yesterday I launch in error the command chmod `-Rv 777 /`

I tried to run these output commands to generate a script to restore the most recent permissions

but when i **restarted the bind9 service** I get the below **error** message:

```
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: starting BIND 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 -u bind
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2'
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: ----------------------------------------------------
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: available at https://www.isc.org/support
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: ----------------------------------------------------
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: found 1 CPU, using 1 worker thread
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: using up to 4096 sockets
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: open: /etc/bind/named.conf: permission denied
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: loading configuration: permission denied
May 29 06:29:31 mydomain named[4635]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

Its says error opening **/etc/bind/named.conf permission denied**

I have tried to search on Google but haven't found anything.

I tried to uninstall, then purge and re-install but bind9 shows the same error

Comment: Improve your formatting of codes

Comment: Okay i did it sorry im new here

Comment: I guess is something like system permissions cuz i reinstalled bind and it shows the same error but i got no idea what can be bad...

Comment: Have u got your problem solved?

Answer (score -3):

BIND9 is available in the **Main repository**. No additional repository needs to be enabled for BIND9.

Before u begin, you should be familiar with RootSudo.

To install the server simply install the bind9 package. See InstallingSoftware for details on using package managers.

A very useful package for testing and troubleshooting DNS issues is the dnsutils package. Also, the BIND9 Documentation can be found in the bind9-doc package.

Login to your server via SSH and run:

```
`apt-get install bind`9
```

**Configuration**:
Open the `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` file and add the following lines on the top of the file.

```
acl trusted {
        127.0.0.1;
};
```

and in the options block add :

```
allow-recursion    {trusted; };
Restart the service

service bind9 restart
```

Check this:https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/doc/bind-9-9/

https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/doc/bind-9-10/
Hopefully u should get your solution.

https://wiki.debian.org/Bind9